# how to transfer data from iphone to apple watch ,when app launches first time in watch - objective c

Tags: ios, iphone

can't able to send data when app launches first time in watch. I able to send data when performing some action using buttons i.e, using connectivity framework.
But when app launches i can't able to transfer data .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code here..

Comment: Actually my iPhone app will display weather and location using location services and in iPhone its working fine,but how can i display weather and location in apple watch.I tried to use connectivity framework its working only after performing some actions but at first launch only blank screen

Comment: @SaiSandeepN: Did you fix this issue, i am having same issue in my app. I need to share the user credentials from Phone to Apple Watch once Apple Watch launches